# What are the differences between "has" vs "has been"?

Tags: differences

In past tense when is it better to use one over the other?

*has been [verb]* vs *has [verb]*

For example:

> ***Your order has been shipped*** vs. ***Your order has shipped***

Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: In the second sentence the object of the verb has been implausibly converted into its subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sentences are correct. As to which is better, it will depend on the context. It would be unusual for someone selling to another person on *eBay* to use the second variation (*Your order has shipped*). But it is the standard usage in notifications from Amazon.

The verb "*ship*" is an example of a transitive/intransitive (or ergative) verb. The object of the transitive clause can become the subject of the intransitive clause. A similar example is:

> Her watch has been broken. / Her watch has broken.

There's a good explanation of this grammatical feature on the Macmillan Dictionary site:

http://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/verbs-in-learners-dictionaries-part-3

Comment: *Has been broken* implies someone broke it, while *has broken* states that it has passed into a non-working condition, keeping open the possibility of this happening spontaneously.  An important distinction in some cases.